# Explain how specific C #define works

Tags: c, algorithm, function

I have been looking at some of the codes at http://www.netlib.org/fdlibm/ to see how some functions work and I was looking at the code for e_log.c and in some parts of the code it says:

```
hx = __HI(x);       /* high word of x */
lx = __LO(x);       /* low  word of x */
```

The code for `__HI(x)` and `__LO(x)` is:

```
#define __HI(x) *(1+(int*)&x)
#define __LO(x) *(int*)&x
```

which I really don't understand because I am not familiar with this type of C. Can someone please explain to me what `__HI(x)` and `__LO(x)` are doing?

Also later in the code for the function there is a statement:

```
__HI(x) = hx|(i^0x3ff00000);
```

Can someone please explain to me:

- how is it possible to make a function equal to something (I generally work with python so I don't really know what is going on)?
- what are `__HI(x)` and `__LO(x)` doing?
- what does the program mean by "high word" and "low word" of x?

The final purpose of my analysis is understanding this code in order to port it into a Python implementation

Comment: `#define name(args)` in C is not actually a function, though maybe you can use it like one in most cases. `#` statements are read by the preprocessor at compile time, and `#define` is creating a macro https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor#Macro_definition_and_expansion

Comment: @RobertoCaboni I have 64 bit...

Comment: Use of reserved identifiers gives undefined behaviour.   Identifiers that start with a double underscore (like your `__HI` and `__LOW`) are reserved, so using them gives undefined behaviour.

Comment: It's undefined behavior for a second reason (other than the use of reserved identifiers which @Peter notes): it violates strict aliasing. It's also _horrible_ code, depending on `int` being a particular size (I guess 32 bit), and the architecture being little-endian. Brrrr.

Comment: @Peter: The behavior is not “undefined” because the code in question is part of fdlibm, which is designed to be part of a C implementation, not to be source code used by ordinary C programs. It is therefore not covered by the rules of the C standard. It is **supposed** to use reserved identifiers because part of the purpose of the C standard reserving identifiers is to reserve them for use by C implementations, so that the names used in an implementation will not conflict with the names used in the subject source code.

Comment: @EricPostpischil - The behaviour is therefore undefined according to the C standard.     The C standard defines, specifically, what it means by "undefined behavior" - which is, essentially, that the C standard specifies no constraints on what happens.    Yes, it is true that implementations are permitted to use and rely on constructs that have undefined behaviour - for which they have defined some specific behaviour.   The fact that an implementation can do that does not conflict with it still being undefined according to the standard.

Comment: The C standard does not define the behavior of this code, but not because it uses two underscores or because the standard says it is not defined. It is because the C standard does not apply to this code, anymore than it applies to assembly code that is used to implement the compiler or the linker or the operating system. This code is not part of a C program as defined by the C standard. It is part of a C implementation, and it happens to be standard-C-like in its appearance, but that is a liberty the implementation is free to take. There is no reason it must conform to the standard’s rules.

Answer (score 3):

These macros use compiler-dependent properties to access the representations of `double` types.

In C, all objects other than bit-fields are represented as sequences of bytes. The fdlibm code you are looking at is designed for implementations where `int` is four bytes and the `double` type is represented using eight bytes in a format defined by the IEEE-754 floating-point specification. That format is called *binary64* or IEEE-754 basic 64-bit binary floating-point. It is also designed for an implementation where the C compiler guarantees that aliasing via pointer conversions is supported. (This is not guaranteed by the C standard, but C implementations may support it.)

Consider a `double` object named `x`. Given these macros:

```
#define __HI(x) *(1+(int*)&x)
#define __LO(x) *(int*)&x
```

When `__LO(x)` is used in source code, it is replaced by `*(int*)&x`. The `&x` takes the address of `x`. The address of `x` has type `double *`. The cast `(int *)` converts this to `int *`, a pointer to an `int`. Then `*` dereferences this pointer, resulting in a reference to the `int` that is at the low-address part of `x`.

When `__HI(x`) is used in the source code, `(int*)&x` again points to the low-address part of `x`. Adding 1 changes it to point to the high-address part. Then `*` dereferences this, resulting in a reference to the `int` that is at the high-address part.

The routines in fdlibm are special mathematical routines. To operate, they need to examine and modify the bytes that represent `double` values. The `__LO` and `__HI` macros give them this access.

These definitions of `__HI` and `__LO` work for implementations that store the `double` values in little-endian order (with the “least significant” part of the double in the lower-addressed memory location). The fdlibm code may contain alternate definitions for big-endian systems, likely selected by some `#if` statement.

In the code `__HI(x) = hx|(i^0x3ff00000);`, the value `0x3ff00000` is a bit mask for the bits that encode the exponent (and part of the significand) of a `double` value. Without context, we cannot say precisely what is happening here, but the code appears to be merging `hx` with some value from `i`. It is likely completing some computation of the bytes representing a new `double` value it is creating and storing those bytes in the “high” part of a `double` object.

Answer (score 1):

I add a reply to integrate the one already present (not substitute).

```
hx = __HI(x);       /* high word of x */
lx = __LO(x);       /* low  word of x */
```

Comments are useful... even if in this case the macro name could be clear enough. "high" and "low" refer to the two halves of an integer representation, typically a 16 or 32 bit because for an 8-bit int the used term is "nibble".

If we take a 16-bit unsigned integer which can range from 0 to 65535, or in hex 0x0000 to 0xFFFF, for example 0x1234, the two halves are:

```
  0x1234
      ^^-------------------- lower half, or "low"
    ^^---------------------- upper half, or "high"
```

Note that "lower" means *the less significant part*. The correct way to get the two halves, assuming 16 bits, is to make a logical (bitwise) AND with 0xFF to get lo(), and to shift 8 bit right (divide by 256) to get high.

Now, inside a CPU the number 0x1234 is written in two consecutive locations, either as 0x12 then 0x34 if big-endian, or 0x34 then 0x12 if little-endian. Given this, other ways are possible to read single halves, reading the correct one directly from memory without calculation. To get the lo() of 0x1234 in a little endian machine, it is possible to read the single byte in the first location.

From the question:

```
#define __HI(x) *(1+(int*)&x)
#define __LO(x) *(int*)&x
```

__LO is defined to make a bitwise AND (sure way), while __HI peeks directly in the memory (less sure). It is strange because it seems that the integer to be splitted in two has double dimension of the size of the word of the machine. If the machine is 32 bit, the integer to be split is 64 bits long. And there is another caveat: those macro can read the halves, but can also be used to **write** separately the two halves. In fact, from the question:

```
__HI(x) = hx|(i^0x3ff00000);
```

the result is to set only the HI part (upper, most significant) of x. Note also the value used, 0x3FFF0000, which seems to indicate that x is 128 bits because the mask used to generate *a half* of it is 64 bits long.

Hope this is clear enough to translate C to python. You should use integers 128 bit long. When in need to get the LO() part, use a bitwise AND with 0xFFFFFFFF; to get HI(), shift right 64 times or do the equivalent division.

When HI and LO are to the left of an assignment, only that half of the value is written, and you should construct separately the two halves and sum them up (or *bitwise or* them together).

Hope it helps...

Comment: Thanks this does help a lot. Just 1 question, because python3 ints are 32 bit what would I do to get the high and low of them.

Comment: Would for LSB  I would do `x&0xFF` and for GSB I would do `x >> 8` where x = any 32-bit integer?

Comment: The integers here are 32 bits wide, they're addressing 2 halves of a `double` (64 bits). The mask you're seeing is 32 bits wide as well. Also, the `&` in the `__LO` macro is address-of, not AND.

Comment: @J.Doe if your machine is 32 bit, you don't get hi and lo. You keep hi and lo as two separate variables, and put them side by side when needed. How to do? I don't know. Perhaps some library (python has tons) able to declare 128-bit integer numbers. Or may be float, I've seen an answer telling that those numbers are float, not integer as I was thinking.

Answer (score 0):

`#define A B`

is a *preprocessor directive* that substitutes literal A with literal B all over the source code before the compilation.

`#define A(x) B`

is a function-like preprocessor macro which uses a parameter `x` in order to do a parameterized preprocessor substitution. In this case, B can be a function of x as well.

### Your macros

```
#define __HI(x) *(1+(int*)&x)
#define __LO(x) *(int*)&x

// called as
__HI(x) = hx|(i^0x3ff00000);
```

Since it is just a matter of code substitution, the assignment is perfectly legit. Why? Because in this case the macro is substituted by an **R-value** in both cases.

That rvalue is in both cases a variable of type `int`:

- take x's address
- cast it to a pointer to int
- deference it (in case of `__LO()`)
- Add 1 and then deference it in case of `__HI ()`.

What it will actually point depends on architecture because pointer arithmetics are architecture dependant. Also endianness has to be taken into account.

What we can say is that they are designed in order to access the *lower* and the *higher* halves **of a data type whose size is `2*sizeof (int)` big** (so, if for example integer data is 32-bit wide, they will allow the access to lower 32 bytes and to upper 32 bytes). Furthermore, from the macro names we understand that it is a little-endian architecture (LSB comes first).

---

In order to port to Python code containing this macros you will need to do it at higher level, since Python does not support pointers.

These **tips** don't solve your specific task, but provide to you a *working method* for this task and similar:

- A way to understand what a macro does is checking how it is actually translated by the preprocessor. This can be done on most compilers through the `-E` compiler option.
- Use a debugger to understand the functionality: set a breakpoint just before the call to the macro, and analyze its effects on addresses and variables.

Comment: So would it be possible to convert that to python somehow?

Comment: @J.Doe Sure, *somehow* it is possible. You need to *understand* what it does, and then you *know* what to do, assuming that you know Python. As it seems, the source at hand only works for little-endian architectures, and it is accessing high and low (32-bit?) halves of a wider value. You may like to use binary operations in Python instead, for example write some real function for this.

Comment: @thebusybee: The source actually defines `__HI` and `__LO` differently based on endianity ([fdmlib.h](http://www.netlib.org/fdlibm/fdlibm.h)). The whole thing is based on knowledge of the raw floating point representation anyway.

Comment: @Hasturkun So the OP needs to understand, not only why and how the macros are working, but what happens on a higher level. However, there should be enough hints to start now. ;-)

Comment: @thebusybee I agree about the fact that C-Pyhton porting can be done only  at an higher level, but in that case a zoom-out of the entire OP's function would have been required. But I also think it is another question (and I wouldn't have answered, since I'm not so skilled in python)

Comment: Talking about "hi" and "low" using "int" type looks pretty suspicious... if the system is 32 bit, hi and low refer to 64-bit integers, and on a 64-bit system that would refer to 128-bit integers. Strange.

Comment: @J.Doe I expanded my answer providing some working method tips for understandig macros and their functionalities. Within a C question is all I can do.